# maven compilation failure on jenkins while release:perform

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, nexus3

I have e job on Jenkins where I want to release an artifact to Nexus. It complains about the mavne-compiler-plugin and maven-release-plugin during perform. Any ideas about what the issue is and how to solve it?

In the Jenkins job I have also check the `Delete workspace before build starts` and added `Check out to specific local branch` set to  'master'

This is the maven command

```
mvn release:clean release:prepare release:perform -DreleaseVersion=${releaseVersion} -DdevelopmentVersion=${developmentVersion} -X
```

and the error looks like this

```
[INFO] [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Release-to-Nexus/target/checkout/src/main/java/com/company/security/jwt/JWTFilter.java:[19,8] cannot access javax.servlet.Filter
[INFO]   class file for javax.servlet.Filter not found
...
...
...
[INFO] [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Total time: 5.919 s
[INFO] [INFO] Finished at: 2018-01-23T17:31:40+00:00
[INFO] [INFO] Final Memory: 41M/361M
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project testrepo: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[INFO] [ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Release-to-Nexus/target/checkout/src/main/java/com/company/security/jwt/JWTFilter.java:[19,8] cannot access javax.servlet.Filter
[INFO] [ERROR] class file for javax.servlet.Filter not found
...
...
...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 02:16 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-01-23T17:31:41+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/217M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:perform (default-cli) on project testrepo: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1' -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:perform (default-cli) on project testrepo: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'
```

From pom.xml

```
...
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
   <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>    
   </configuration>
</plugin>
...
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.3</version>
   <configuration>
      <tagNameFormat>v@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
      <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
      <releaseProfiles>releases</releaseProfiles>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
...
       <profile>
            <id>releases</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.5.1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>default-deploy</id>
                                <phase>deploy</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>deploy</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <serverId>nexus-releases</serverId>
                            <nexusUrl>https://nexus.url/</nexusUrl>
                            <skipStaging>true</skipStaging>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
```

`java -version`

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-8u151-b12-0ubuntu0.16.04.2-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

`javac -version`

```
javac 1.8.0_151
```

`mvn -version`

```
Java version: 1.8.0_151, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: ANSI_X3.4-1968
OS name: "linux", version: "4.4.0-109-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

`lsb_release -a`

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is raised by the maven-compiler-plugin, so it has to do with *compilation*. In fact, the error is a simple compilation error due to a "symbol not found" in code.

You should add this dependency to your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And with this specific library, it is a good idea to set it also with `scope=provided`.